# Query about functions

Tags: general-topology, functions

Suppose that we have a function $f:(\mathbb{R^2},d_2) \to (\mathbb{R^2},d_2) $ where $d_2$ is the Euclidean metric. A function in this case looks like what exactly. Since we are in $\mathbb{R^2}$ the function could look like $f(x,y)=(x-1,y+2)$ right? If this is the case then what would be meant by $d_2(f(x),f(y))$. Maybe someone could clarify why I'm confused, or if I am just wrong in general about how I am thinking about this.

Comment: You state that $f:(\mathbb{R^2},d_2) \to (\mathbb{R^2},d_2) $ where $d_2$ is the metric  however this is exactly the same as $f:(\mathbb{R^2}) \to (\mathbb{R^2}) $.  $d_2$ the metric need not be included.

Comment: $d_2$ is the function that measures the distance between two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  This has nothing to do at all with $f$.

Comment: And you're still writing $f(x,y)$ and $f(x)$, which makes no sense.  $f$ is either a function of one variable or two, not both.

Comment: @Thehomeschooler well, it definitely needs to be included if you are going to ponder the continuity of $f$ with respect to the domain and codomain metrics (which could be different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is defined as follows.

Let $x = (x_{1},x_{2})\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $y = (y_{1},y_{2})\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
d_{2}(x,y) = \sqrt{(x_{1} - y_{1})^{2} + (x_{2} - y_{2})^{2}}
\end{align*}

If we have two functions $f(x,y) = (f_{1}(x,y),f_{2}(x,y))$ and $g(x,y) = (g_{1}(x,y),g_{2}(x,y))$, then
\begin{align*}
d_{2}(f(x,y),g(x,y)) = \sqrt{(f_{1}(x,y) - g_{1}(x,y))^{2} + (f_{2}(x,y) - g_{2}(x,y))^{2}}
\end{align*}

More generally, we can define the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as follows.

Let $x = (x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n})$ and $y = (y_{1},y_{2},\ldots,y_{n})$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
d_{2}(x,y) = \sqrt{(x_{1}-y_{1})^{2} + (x_{2}-y_{2})^{2} + \ldots + (x_{n}-y_{n})^{2}}
\end{align*}

More generally, we can talk about metric spaces.

Given a set $X$, we say the function $d_{X}:X\times X\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ is a metric iff given $x\in X$, $y\in X$ and $z\in  X$, we have

(a) $d_{X}(x,y) \geq 0$ and $d_{X}(x,y) = 0$ iff $x = y$.

(b) $d_{X}(x,y) = d_{X}(y,x)$ for every $x$ and $y$.

(c) $d_{X}(x,z) \leq d_{X}(x,y) + d_{X}(y,z)$ for every $x$, $y$ and $z$.

In the case of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, there are two examples whose presentation is standard.

More precisely, given $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, one has that
\begin{align*}
d_{1}(x,y) = |x_{1} - y_{1}| + |x_{2} - y_{2}| + \ldots + |x_{n} - y_{n}|
\end{align*}
which is known as the taxi-cab metric.

Another example is given below:

\begin{align*}
d_{\infty}(x,y) = \max\{|x_{1} - y_{1}|, |x_{2}  - y_{2}|,\ldots, |x_{n} - y_{n}|\}
\end{align*}

Besides such examples, there are plenty of metric spaces.

If you still want to go further, you can study Topology, which generalizes the ideas previously presented.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are confused because you’re using $x,y$ to denote two different things:

1. Coordinates $(x,y)$ of a vector $X \in \mathbb R^2$.
2. Vectors of $\mathbb R^2$ when you write $d(f(x),f(y))$.

This is not an issue usually, except when you’re working on both concepts at the same time. What you’re doing.

Denote $X_1=(x_1,y_1), X_2=(x_2,y_2)$ two vectors will avoid the ambiguity you have.

$d_2(f(X_1),f(X_2))$ means the Euclidean distance between the images of $X_1,X_2$ under $f$.

The map  $f$ is independent from the distance $d_2$ itself. **What is not independent from the metric, $d_2$ in your example are some properties of the map $f$. Continuity for example.** For such properties, the metric is crucial as a map may be continuous for a metric but not related to another one.

Answer (score 1):

The presence of the distances in the definition of $f$ clarifies which topologies we are to use when talking about stuff like continuity for example. What is meant by $d_2(f(x, y), f(z, w))$ is exactly the only thing that can be meant (note that $f$ has two inputs, whilst in your original question it had only one- which is not necessarily a mistake if you also mention $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2,$ for example). In your particular example, we would have $$d_2(f(x,y), f(z, w)) = \Vert (x - 1, y + 2) - (z - 1, w + 2) \Vert = \Vert (x - z, y - w) \Vert = \sqrt{(x - z)^2 + (y - w)^2} = d_2((x, y), (z, w))$$ for instance.

What you should take away from all of this is that sometimes we are not working with the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which we all know and love and the topologies actually dictate what continuity means for functions between those two spaces. :)